# Remove extra blank line at the end of algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

Here's how to recreate the situation:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}    
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered, nofillcomment]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
...
\begin{algorithm}[H]
     \eIf{\Phi}{\KwRet{a}}{\KwRet{b}}
\end{algorithm}
...
```

[image]

I found that the extra blank line is caused by the `\Phi` in the if condition.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Your MWE is not complete, however, If I add missed code, it works fine. No empty last line. You may try to update your LaTeX installation.

Comment: You should get an error where TeX complains about a missing `$`. So, try `$\Phi$`.

Comment: The lack of $$ is the reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After completing your code fragment with missed code (`$`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`), your code fragment works as expected:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
% \usepackage{algpseudocode}  % not needed in this example

\begin{document}   % <--- added
\begin{algorithm}[H]
     \eIf{$\Phi$}{\KwRet{a}}{\KwRet{b}} % <--- added $
 \caption{???}     % <--- added (but not needed)
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}     % <--- added
```

[image]

Comment: The lack of $$ is the reason. Thank you.